# How can i modify XAML elements from another class (C#-WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am trying to connect a class called Engine with XAML elements, to be more specific I have a LevelWindow.xaml where a grid exists. I want to split that grid (in rows and columns ) from Engine class, the split code exists, but when the programs is running Engine is not changing grid from LevelWindow .... I tryed to semi-use bindings, but i cant find any way to Bind the GRID .... some sugestions ?

> **Engine**

[image]

Comment: Engine seems to be what we call a view model. Search the web for MVVM and WPF Data Binding.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i found some good tutorials, but they don't correspond with my necessity. My question is, can Grid and only grid be binded ... ?

Comment: don't use bitmaps to post what ought to be text. pictures of your code are useless. Question asking for help getting code to work which don't include a [mcve] are useless. Please improve the question if you want help.

Comment: How I said in the question, I have Engine class, which should split a grid in rows and columns, but in my LevelWindow.XAML, UI element ( grid ) , doest not change, is not splitted after the program runs. In LevelWindow, the grid does not contain nothing, is just <Grid name="..." .. />, and I am trying to find a way to modify grid from Engine class, i tried bindings tutorials, but i can't find nothing about binding grid ... . And sorry for the misunderstanding, I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use your existing splitting code and that it doesn't support binding and/or notify property changed, you can perhaps find some way to perform what you want using a ContentControl instead of your Grid in your xaml file.
Then Bind the contentControl content property to a grid that you instantiate in your Engine (thus you can access and modify it's inner properties like grid column/rows).

Yet it's quite horrible to perform graphic control instantiation in your business class...

Link to MSDN contentcontrol :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx